# How can i pull a variable from an button Action function to another view controller class?

Tags: swift, firebase

I have a block of code

```
@IBAction func postbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
   let ref: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference()
   let postvalue =  ref.child("All Post").childByAutoId()
   let postkeyvalue = postvalue.key!
   postvalue.child("Post Content").setValue(postcontent.text)
   postvalue.child("Post Author").setValue(currentuser)
   var possstkeystring = postkeyvalue
}
```

I need to access the possstkeystring in my other view controller file.

I have already tried declaring the possstkeystring outside of the function. When I do that, my project always fail because it's empty.

I have tried using the prepare function that didn't work.

I tried declaring the variable outside of the class- that didn't work.
It always failed because the string was empty, and since its a firebase child string, it cant be empty.

Here is my other file block of code I'm trying to plug this into

```
self.ref.child("All Post").child(possstkeystring).child("Post Author").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
     if let item = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
       { 
          self.authornamereference = item["Post Author"] as! String
       }
```

please help! thanks :)

When I actually input the variable outside of scope or in a static variable, I get this error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

Comment: you can make that vaiable static then it will be accessed from other VC.

Comment: hey! thanks for the tip ! i've tried that as well. i put it inside a struct (it seems thats that only way to make a static variable)

Comment: public static is not good option to code in object oriented para time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways, One of the ways is to use NotificationCenter

Using NotificationCenter:

First you need to add extension to Notification.Name anywhere in your App. Like

```
extension Notification.Name { static let mynotification = Notification.Name("mynotification") }
```

In your Another View controller viewDidLoad method add

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourMethod), name: NSNotification.Name.mynotification, object: nil)
```

Then in your Another ViewController add a method which will be called when notification fired

```
 func yourMethod(){
    //// do something
 }
```

Now in your Click event method or even anywhere from app, you can call viewController's method by sending notification Like

```
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.mynotification, object: nil)
```

2. Another Easy way to, if you started Another ViewController from this same viewController where the click event is present, then You must have the reference of the viewController. then you need to just call

   ```
   vc.yourMethod(params);
   ```

Comment: Let me know if you have any further query.